# Am I writing this right? [noob]

Tags: android, arrays, random, audio, int

```
 private final int NUM_SOUND_FILES = 4;
 private Random rnd = new Random(4);
 private int mfile[] = new mfile[NUM_SOUND_FILES]; //the second mfile 
                                                      //reports error everytime
 mfile[0] = R.raw.sound1;
 mfile[1] = R.raw.sound2;
 mfile[2] = R.raw.sound3;
 mfile[3] = R.raw.sound4;

 int sndToPlay = rnd.nextInt(NUM_SOUND_FILES);
```

I keep getting syntax errors no matter how I write it.  And when I get the syntax right, it forcecloses.  Here's with the alleged "correct" syntax but forcecloses:

```
private final int NUM_SOUND_FILES = 4;
private Random rnd = new Random(4);
private int mfile[] = new int[NUM_SOUND_FILES];{
mfile[0] = R.raw.sound1;
mfile[1] = R.raw.sound2;
mfile[2] = R.raw.sound3;
mfile[3] = R.raw.sound4;}
```

Comment: Where is "R" and why not use contructor for initialization?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by 'foreclose'?

Comment: I think by forcelose he's talking about the android application forces the user to close because of an exception. What exception is thrown?

@Petar: R is a generated class by Android

Comment: @Sebi Ah, thanks:) I haven't used Android in my life:)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an android developer but that array declaration on line 3 doesn't look right to me, normally its an array of type int which would be declared as below:

```
private int[] mfile = new int[NUM_SOUND_FILES];
```

Comment: I got it working thanks to a guy named Mark...the whole code needed a little reworking...only trouble I'm having now is the sound not restarting when another .create is made...this is gonna be harder than I thought :P

Comment: might be a good idea to put the working code on as the answer, you can accept your own answer if its the closest fix.